# Residue theorem for rational function with high degree denominator

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

$$\int\limits_0^\infty \frac{x^2dx}{(x^4+4)^2} $$

In my complex analysis class problem list I have this integral, it's supposed to be solved by residue theorem. My first attempt was to apply it directly, but calculations in poles were too bad. Then I tried to use substitute, but failed. Looks like it's impossible to make this function a sum of elementary fractions.

So currently I'm looking for a proper substitute or a trick which would let me to use residue theorem without troubles,thanks.

Comment: What was so bad about it? Looks like a standard application of the residue theorem to me. That said, this can also be solved by partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: I you want to simplify the evaluation via the reduction of a number of poles, I would recommend the substitution $t=x^4$ first: $\displaystyle I=\frac{1}{4}\int_0^\infty\frac{t^{-\frac{1}{4}}}{(1+t)^2}dt.\,\,$ 
Now you can use the keyhole contour with the only pole of second order inside.
You can make the evaluation even simpler if notice that $\displaystyle \int_0^\infty\frac{t^{-\frac{1}{4}}}{(1+t)^2}dt=-\frac{\partial}{\partial a}\bigg|_{a=1}\int_0^\infty\frac{t^{-\frac{1}{4}}}{a+t}dt$ - getting the pole of the first order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the similar integral

$$I=\int_0^\infty \frac{x^2}{(x^4+1)^2}dx$$

Under the variable interchange $x\leftrightarrow\frac{1}{x}$ we get

$$I = \int_0^\infty\frac{x^4}{(x^4+1)^2}dx = \int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^4+1}-\frac{1}{(x^4+1)^2}dx$$

It is easier to apply residue theorem to the simple pole and the order two pole with a trivial numerator. Can you think of how to apply this to your integral?

Comment: Well I can take out 1/16 from the fraction and then substitute x =u sqrt(2), as a result - integral you pointed * const